# The most effective string replace alogrithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, replace

We know that most code editors implement the string search with the Boyer-Moore algorithm.How does it implements the string replace algorithm, Any idea?

Comment: if you're not to lazy, download the source code from http://www.openoffice.org/download/source/ and take a look. You may also share your results with us.

Comment: What else is required for a string replace other than a string search?

Comment: An actual replace action :)

Comment: I guess it depends on the data structure used for the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that nowadays most text editors use either a single block of memory to hold the entire file, or an array of lines or blocks of larger size, each of which points to its own block of memory.  (In the past there have been more interesting techniques employed.  One way is to have all text to the left or above the cursor position "pressed against" the left end of a fixed-size buffer, and all text to the right or below "pressed against" the right end, with a gap of free space in the middle.  Then the common operations of inserting or deleting characters can take place in constant time!  Moving the cursor k positions to the right entails sliding k bytes from the left end of the right segment to the right end of the left segment, i.e. moving the cursor is now a linear time operation!)

Assuming that the text is stored in an "ordinary" way (i.e. not the left-right cursor-dependent buffer pair described above), there aren't too many ways to optimise replace operations, especially if the replacement text is longer than the search text -- in this case, there is no escaping the fact that the rest of the line/block/file must be shunted forward in memory for each replacement.  The best you can do there is to avoid multiple O(n) copy operations when one will do -- i.e. *don't* delete the search string, then insert the replacement string one character at a time, shunting the rest of the line/block/document forward one character at a time, because the latter step will cost O(n^2) time.  Instead, shunt the rest of the document text far enough forward to make room for the replacement string in one O(n) step.

If the replacement string is shorter than the search text, you can scan forward with two pointers `from` and `to`, always copying from one to the other.  As replacements are made, `to` will start to lag behind `from`.  This is safe because `to <= from` always holds, so you will never write over something you have to read later.

Actually, if the replacement string is longer than the search string, and no suffix of the search string is also a prefix of the search string, then you can safely scan *backwards* from the end in one O(n) pass.  The suffix/prefix requirement is necessary to avoid situations like the following, which would produce different behaviour depending on the scan direction:

```
Search and replace "abcabc" with "xyz" in document text "abcabcabc":
S&R using forward algo gives:  xyzabc
S&R using backward algo gives: abcxyz
```